# Как получить текстовое сообщение из перехваченного пакета?

Tags: c#, .net, сокет, tcp, пакет

сделал программу, которая отправляет/принимает сообщения от такой же программы которая выступает сервером. Использовал классы TcpClient и NetworkStream. Отправляю сообщения данным способом и всё работает.

```
byte[] messagebuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtMessage.Text);
stream.Write(messagebuffer, 0, messagebuffer.Length);
```

Сделал по примерам из интернета сниффер, который перехватывает пакеты из указанного IP.

```
socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()), int.Parse(tbPort.Text)));
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, true);

byte[] byInc = new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
byte[] byOut = new byte[4];
buffer = new byte[4096];
socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, byInc, byOut);
socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnReceive, null);
```

Получаю перехваченные буфер данных и закидываю в готовый класс из интернета:
https://pastebin.com/qCQ5eWiS

Отправляю с клиента/сервера сообщение: "test" и перехватываю пакет сниффером. Пытаюсь вывести данные, но отображается кракозябра. В чём проблема?

Comment: Покажите как вы пытаетесь вывести данные, возможно проблема именно в этом.

Comment: @LLENN В richtextbox1 с помощью `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(currentPacket.Buffer)`

Comment: @LLENN currentPacket  это `Packet currentPacket = new Packet(buf, len);` Полученный буфер и его длина